# Is Harmonica Mugig 10-hole 20-tone Blues Harp similar to the others in view of blows and draws?

Tags: harmonica

I've just started learning to play (diatonic) harmonica, and here is my Mugig 10-hole 20-tone Blues Harp:

[image]

Its instruction manual illustrates the note pattern as the following:

[image]

But it actually contradicts the blow-draw pattern explained in most of the books including [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Complete-Idiots-Guide-Playing-Harmonica/dp/1592574653) that says:

[image]

For example, books often say that the first hole's notes are `C` and `D` in the case of blowing and drawing, respectively; however, my harmonica instruction claims something completely reversed!

When I try simple songs based on what the instruction says, the sound is not exactly what it should be; however, I'm a beginner and my solfege skills are poor, so I can not exactly find out whether the instruction manual is correct or not.

Does anybody have any experience to use such kind of harmonica?

**Update 1:**

Here are some tests:

- [Blow hole 1](https://vocaroo.com/delete/s17gQuHkt0jr/f4bd99088df6dd2f)
- [Draw hole 1](https://vocaroo.com/delete/s13l4438CUGR/536dbabb7fc8da8c)
- [Blow hole 2](https://vocaroo.com/delete/s1hYW9WHtDwK/e7e2c5a0c06abebd)
- [Draw hole 2](https://vocaroo.com/delete/s1l1scGfAtJw/4dc8666348d8b2a8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is odd!

I've never seen that before in my life.  According to your booklet, it is exactly the same as a normal harmonica, except completely backwards.

My guess would be the arrows in the book are wrong rather than the harmonica, but who knows.

Could you post a recording of simply playing a chord, blowing, and then drawing?  Doesn't have to be accurate or single notes or anything, just picking it up and blowing then inhaling will be enough to tell.

**Update**: I can tell from your recording that this is indeed correct: the booklet is just printed wrong and the harmonica has the normal layout.  That being said, it's also not perfectly in tune and probably is never going to sound 100% right.  If you have fun with this harmonica, then buy yourself a proper instrument, they're not crazy expensive, and you'll be able to enjoy something that will sound in tune.

For example, hohner special 20s are fantastic.  A hohner big river is fine, and suzuki/lee oskar both make decent affordable harmonicas. Easttop now makes very affordable chinese-made harmonicas: they are the first Chinese company to make a decent blues harp, and in fact they're *very* good.  What you have, unfortunately, is more of a toy than an instrument.

Comment: Can you please check the applied update? I recorded four tests corresponding to the first two holes of the instrument.

Comment: @Roboticist can you use soundcloud or vocaroo or something?   
 The website you've linked to is err... well it's unique I'll give it that... Soundcloud is better because it doesn't expire, but vocaroo.com is very quick and easy

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences. I just uploaded them in vocaroo. Please check the updated links.

Comment: @Roboticist in case you haven't seen, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be Richter tuning, where the bottom octave is designed to provide two triads - I blowing, and V drawing. The middle and top part provide full diatonic scale notes, but missing the B draw at the very top. All this provides a simple triad of C in this case when blowing anywhere, with a G9 sound sucking above the bottom octave. So, apart from the bottom octave and the top two notes, it's just like an ordinary mouth organ.

Comment: Tim, you might want to take another look at this one, you've missed the mark entirely